# C# JsonSerializer Ожидается состояние "Element".. Обнаружен "Text" с именем "", пространство имен ""

Tags: c#, json

Имеется JSON строка (точно валидная)

```
string html = {"CardPAN":"9643905403305906125","TripsHistory":[{"Time":"01.07.2016 13:49:12","RouteNum":"98","RouteDesc":null,"RouteType":"ком. автобус","CompanyName":"ООО \"Новосибирскпрофстрой ПАТП-1\"","Summa":1900},{"Time":"01.07.2016 14:46:09","RouteNum":"LENIN","RouteDesc":null,"RouteType":"метро","CompanyName":"Метрополитен","Summa":2000},{"Time":"28.06.2016 11:07:09","RouteNum":"98","RouteDesc":null,"RouteType":"ком. автобус","CompanyName":"ООО \"Новосибирскпрофстрой ПАТП-1\"","Summa":1900},{"Time":"28.06.2016 11:54:14","RouteNum":"STUD","RouteDesc":null,"RouteType":"метро","CompanyName":"Метрополитен","Summa":2000},{"Time":"28.06.2016 13:57:28","RouteNum":"7","RouteDesc":null,"RouteType":"мун. троллейбус","CompanyName":"Филиал №3 \"Ленинский троллейбусный\" МКП \"ГЭТ\"","Summa":1800}]}
```

Я использую нативный **System.Runtime.Serialization.Json**
Вот классы сериализации:

```
[DataContract]
public class Trip
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Time")]
    public string Time { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "RouteNum")]
    public string RouteCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "RouteDesc")]
    public string RouteDesc { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "RouteType")]
    public string RouteType { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "CompanyName")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Summa")]
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class TripHistory
{
    [DataMember(Name = "CardPAN")]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "TripsHistory")]
    public List<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
}
```

Ошибка появляется в следующий строчке

```
var tripHistory = (TripHistory)json.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(html)));
```

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
>
> Additional information: **Ожидается состояние "Element".. Обнаружен
>   "Text" с именем "", пространство имен "".**

Comment: А что в вашем `html`?

Comment: В html json который указан в самом начале вопроса. Прогоняю через MemoryStream по тому что ReadObject требует объект Stream.

Comment: Окей, тогда вопрос о двойных ``\\``. Откуда они? Кажется, у вас невалидный JSON. Не выкусываете ли вы случайно его из текста на javascript?

Comment: Нет это возвращаемый ajax. Нет, даже после исправления ошибка не изменилась.

Comment: Странно, у меня ошибка ушла. Вот такой входной файл: http://pastebin.com/YqrmXqAp и код `string json = File.ReadAllText("x.json"); var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TripHistory)); var tripHistory = (TripHistory)serializer.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)));` у меня отрабатывают.

Comment: Подставив Ваш код, действительно сериализуется. Полагаю где то у меня была крайне не приятная и мало заметная опечатка. Оформите как ответ пожалуйста и Вам упадет плюсик в карму)

Comment: Готово, написал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По результатам дискуссии в комментариях:

Код

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("x.json");
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TripHistory));
var tripHistory = (TripHistory)serializer.ReadObject(
        new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)));
```

читает и десериализует следующий файл:

```
{
    "CardPAN":"9643905403305906125",
    "TripsHistory": [
        {"Time":"01.07.2016 13:49:12","RouteNum":"98","RouteDesc":null,"RouteType":"ком.автобус","CompanyName":"ООО \"Новосибирскпрофстрой ПАТП-1\"","Summa":1900},
        {"Time":"01.07.2016 14:46:09","RouteNum":"LENIN","RouteDesc":null,"RouteType":"метро","CompanyName":"Метрополитен","Summa":2000},
        {"Time":"28.06.2016 11:07:09","RouteNum":"98","RouteDesc":null,"RouteType":"ком.автобус","CompanyName":"ООО \"Новосибирскпрофстрой ПАТП-1\"","Summa":1900},
        {"Time":"28.06.2016 11:54:14","RouteNum":"STUD","RouteDesc":null,"RouteType":"метро","CompanyName":"Метрополитен","Summa":2000},
        {"Time":"28.06.2016 13:57:28","RouteNum":"7","RouteDesc":null,"RouteType":"мун.троллейбус","CompanyName":"Филиал №3 \"Ленинский троллейбусный\" МКП \"ГЭТ\"","Summa":1800}
    ]
}
```

Отличие от первоначального текста — одинарные бекслеши вместо двойных (и форматирование, которое по идее ни на что не влияет).